# Python regex mapping values

Tags: python, regex

```
<input type="hidden" name="rsv.usePoint" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="rsv.yadRequestFlg" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="rsv.ybnNo" value="100-0000">
<input type="hidden" name="rsv.cardSettleFlg" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="rsv.cancelFee" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="rsv.checkoutTime" value="10:00">
<input type="hidden" name="rsv.realUsePoint" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="rsv.payReal" value="7020">
<input type="hidden" name="rsv.csBulkSettleFlg" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="rsv.canType" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="rsv.serviceDv" value="00">
<input type="hidden" name="rsv.stayTime" value="">
```

what is the best way using python regex to extract
all names and all values?
I was thinking about get a list of 
names = ['rsv.usePoint', 'rsv.yadRequestFlg', 'rsv.ybnNo',......'rsv.stayTime']

values = [0,0,'100-0000'....... none].

Zip them into a dict and push to a database. 
 I'm new to regex matching and trimming,  appreciate if somebody could provide some insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should *not* use regex to parse any sort of HTML, which can be nested content.  That being said, if your input really be limited to what you posted above, then `re.findall` can handle this task:

```
inp = """<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rsv.usePoint\" value=\"0\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rsv.yadRequestFlg\" value=\"0\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rsv.ybnNo\" value=\"100-0000\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rsv.cardSettleFlg\" value=\"0\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rsv.cancelFee\" value=\"0\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rsv.checkoutTime\" value=\"10:00\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rsv.realUsePoint\" value=\"0\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rsv.payReal\" value=\"7020\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rsv.csBulkSettleFlg\" value=\"0\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rsv.canType\" value=\"0\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rsv.serviceDv\" value=\"00\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rsv.stayTime\" value=\"\">"""

matches = re.findall(r'\bname="(.*?)" value="(.*?)"', inp)
names =  [i[0] for i in matches]
values =  [i[1] for i in matches]
print(names)
print(values)
```

This prints:

```
['rsv.usePoint', 'rsv.yadRequestFlg', 'rsv.ybnNo', 'rsv.cardSettleFlg', 'rsv.cancelFee',
 'rsv.checkoutTime', 'rsv.realUsePoint', 'rsv.payReal', 'rsv.csBulkSettleFlg',
 'rsv.canType', 'rsv.serviceDv', 'rsv.stayTime']
['0', '0', '100-0000', '0', '0', '10:00', '0', '7020', '0', '0', '00', '']
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, works like a charm, going to read up on re.findall

Comment: @Lenny_Liu I just noticed that you seem to actually want separate lists for the names and values.  I have updated my answer to do this.

Comment: actually, the old solution you provided is better. sorry to confuse you, this is what I want as a result.  
matches = re.findall(r'\bname="(.*?)" value="(.*?)"',inp)

Comment: No issues...then just consume `matches` above in my answer, which is already a 2D list in the format you want.